# Custom button sizes in pixels

Tags: android

At last i finished my work and now i need to hand it to designer. App has some buttons and checkboxes.

So the question how big button and checkbox should she draw for each screen size(ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi) or she could draw just one image for button and anotherone for checbox and it could be scaled?

Thank you already.

Comment: check out 9-patch the guys at google highly recommend it

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: If you put the button graphic in the mdpi dir, it gets scaled to other screen sizes.

Comment: @Christine but what should image size be in pixels?

Comment: That depends on how big you want the buttons to be. I recommend you follow MikeIsraels advice, use 9patches. For a 9patch, you make the buttons as small as possible, with the corners the right size, and 9patch will stretch them for you. The actual size you determint in your layout file, or you let Android determine it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how big your buttons are. U can check the following link for sizes:
http://developer.android.com/images/screens_support/screens-densities.png

But I agree with Mikelsreal (create a 9 patch image).

Create the button image in whatever size u like.

- Add black pixels above the image to set where the image should be stretch horizontal.
- Add black pixels on the left side of the image to set where the image should be stretch vertical.
- Add black pixels on the right side where the content can be placed vertical
- Add black pixels below the image to set where the content can be placen horizontal

rename the image like : yourImageName.9.png

and it should work.
for more info check (developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)